# How to calculate page load time using coded UI Testing?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am using coded `UI Testing` for automation testing. I want to calculate exact page load time using this. Is it possible to calculate this? Or is there any alternate way to do this calculation?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily something you would test with Coded UI tests, Coded UI tests are for testing the functionality of buttons, etc.

I believe load testing would be your solution.  This page has some details about that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404705.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could try monitoring the performance counters that your browser has.

An example on performance counters useful for web page testing:
http://geekswithblogs.net/joycsharp/archive/2009/02/19/top-10-favorite-performance-counters-in-web-site-load-testing.aspx